# Laravel, leer variables env dentro de listeners

Tags: laravel, eventos

Estoy en el listener que reaciona al evento de registro de un usuario.
La idea es mandar un mail al administrador, pero no puedo leer la variable env() que tiene el mail general.

```
    public function handle(UserRegistered $event )
    {
                $User = $event->user();
// ninguna de estas tres formas me devuelve el valor
dd(env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), config('mail.MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'), getenv('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS') );
                $mailable = new AdminUserRegistered( $User );
                $mailDestino = env('MAIL_USERNAME');
                $mailDestino = env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS');
                Mail::to( $mailDestino )->send( $mailable );
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Porqué tienes la asignación a `$mailDestino` 2 veces?

Comment: Lo del `env` no creo que te sea conveniente, pues es un dato que tienes en `config`. Pero al helper `config` asegúrate de que le estás pasando las claves correctas, si está [por default puedes ver](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/1ad5a8d6e0177d7998fa4ee19a43d135a16d2d42/config/mail.php#L86) que la primer clave es `from` y la segunda es `address`.

Comment: Ohhh !!!!   gracias a todos!!!! me siento medio tonto por el error que tuve y no lo ví !!
Es lo que me decías tú Portocerros !!  el from estaba dentro de una clave compuesta en config!!! y por más que la tenía delante, nunca ví ese detalle !!!!!  :( 
- también me sirvió lo tuyo BetaM, probé un ejemplo creando mi propio archivo de configuraciones,  pero entiendo entonces que básicamente, ha de usarse config() por sobre env() para clases fuera de controllers y views.    GRacias!!

Comment: ( ups.. no se como marcar la pregunta como respondida )

Comment: Está bien así, si consideras que se responde a tu pregunta con la otra, de la que se indica que ésta, es un duplicado. Respondiendo a "ha de usarse config() por sobre env() para clases fuera de controllers y views", yo diría "ha de usarse `env` sólo en los archivos dentro del directory `/config`, fuera de ahí, usar `config`"

Comment: Ahh genial Portocerros, por lo que me comentas, entonces env() solo debería estar dentro de los archivos /config, sin embargo, me crea cierta dudas, pues env() se usa mucho como view helper, y creo entonces que lo correcto es como decis usar config().    En realidad, la respuesta completa, salió a partir de lo que me han comentado aquí. El otro link, no termino de hacer respuesta completa a mi post.